# парсинг Python Как обойти защиту сайта?

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Есть код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pyautogui

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

url = 'https://5140.org/fops/page-1'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r"/media/anatolii/Data/Python_lern/pythonProject/all_tov/chromedriver")

driver.get(url)

driver.add_cookie({'name': 'foo', 'value': 'bar'})

time.sleep(5)

# x, y = pyautogui.position()
# print(x, y)
pyautogui.click(1213, 204)
time.sleep(3)
login = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'loginform-email')
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'loginform-password')
time.sleep(3)
login.send_keys('mail@mail.ru')
time.sleep(2)
password.send_keys('password')
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.click(1183, 501)
```

Не дает залогиниться, видит что бот... Подскажите, как обойти ?

Comment: как ты думаешь, для чего делают защиту от ботов?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Буду думать

Comment: Добавил fake_useragent и поместил все в while true. Ничего не поменялось. Выдает ошибки:    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=104.0.5112.101)
Дело в этом конкретном сайте 100%, с другими сайтами работает